# Checking the equivalence relations of sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

$S=\{0,1,2,3\}, R:SxS, (m,n)\in R \text{ if } m+n=4$.

From the condition of $R$, I found that $R=\{(2,2),(1,3),(3,1)\}$.

Now I have to see if $R$ is reflexive, symmetric, antisymmetric, and transitive.

$R$ is not reflexive because $(0,0), (1,1), (3,3) \not\in R$.

$R$ is symmetric because $(1,3), (3,1)\in R$.

$R$ is not antisymmetric because $(1,3), (3,1)\in R$ and $1\not=3$.

$R$ is not transitive because $(1,1)\not\in R$.

I am not really sure if  I did this correctly. Specifically the showing that $R$ is transitive. $R$ is transitive whenever $(a,b)\in R \text{ and } (b,c) \in R$, then $(a,c) \in R \text{ for all } a,b,c \in A$. Does it matter that $(2,2) \in R$? Also did I do the others correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did find $R$ correctly, and each of the four lines beginning with $R$ is correct. However, I'm not exactly sure what the question is that you are trying to answer; the title of your question made me think you just wanted to know whether or not it was an equivalence relation. If that were so, you only needed to show that it isn't transitive.

Comment: I was actually supposed to show that the four properties were true. and I thought if all cases were true then it was an equivalence relation.

Comment: Antisymmetric is not part of the definition of an equivalence relation. (The prefix 'anti' basically means 'opposite of'.) You can see the definitions on Wikipedia if you'd like.